# Print list items with a header

Tags: python, list

If I have a list defined as `list=['Ford','Mustang','1966','red']`
and try to print it my output would look like:
Ford Mustang 1966 red

But how can I achieve to have a heading so the output would look like:

```
Brand Modell Year Color
Ford Mustang 1966 Red
```

That would look much more professional.

Comment: And why you cannot do that? Put the header in another list and print.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Any reason why `print "Brand Model Year Color"` doesn't suffice?

Answer (score 6):

```
LAYOUT = "{!s:10} {!s:14} {!s:4} {!s:10}"

yourList = ["Ford","Mustang",1966,"Red"]

print LAYOUT.format("Brand","Modell","Year","Color")
print LAYOUT.format(*yourList)
```

produces output in columns which will line up (so long as you don't exceed the field width specifiers!), ie

```
Brand      Modell         Year Color     
Ford       Mustang        1966 Red       
Mercedes   F-Cell         2011 White
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
print 'Brand', 'Modell', 'Year', 'Color'
print ' '.join(yourList)
```

?

*P.S.: Don't name your variable `list`!*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python expert, but couldn't you just create an associative list, where the keys are the header names?

Comment: Sure, but dictionaries are unordered.

Answer (score 0):

header = ['Brand', 'Modell', 'Year', 'Color']

car = ['Ford','Mustang','1966','red']

print("\t".join(header) + "\n" + "\t".join(car))